# How to use loops with fetch and Promise.all?

Tags: javascript

So I was following along an MDN article on promises and was wondering how to modify the following code to be able to work for any number of files (not just 3).

```
function fetchAndDecode(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
    if(!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    } else {
      if(response.headers.get("content-type") === "image/jpeg") {
        return response.blob();
      } else if(response.headers.get("content-type") === "text/plain") {
        return response.text();
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(`There has been a problem with your fetch operation for resource "${url}": ` + e.message);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log(`fetch attempt for "${url}" finished.`);
  })
}

let coffee = fetchAndDecode('coffee.jpg');
let tea = fetchAndDecode('tea.jpg');
let description = fetchAndDecode('description.txt');

Promise.all([coffee, tea, description]).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
  // Store each value returned from the promises in separate variables; create object URLs from the blobs
  let objectURL1 = URL.createObjectURL(values[0]);
  let objectURL2 = URL.createObjectURL(values[1]);
  let descText = values[2];

  // Display the images in <img> elements
  let image1 = document.createElement('img');
  let image2 = document.createElement('img');
  image1.src = objectURL1;
  image2.src = objectURL2;
  document.body.appendChild(image1);
  document.body.appendChild(image2);

  // Display the text in a paragraph
  let para = document.createElement('p');
  para.textContent = descText;
  document.body.appendChild(para);
});
```

MDN specifically notes that "If you were improving this code, you might want to loop through a list of items to display, fetching and decoding each one, and then loop through the results inside Promise.all(), running a different function to display each one depending on what the type of code was. This would make it work for any number of items, not just three." I'm not sure how to do this though, and would appreciate help. Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing specific to promises about this. The promise code itself will not change. It's just replacing the repetitive parts of the code with loops that do the same thing.

Comment: @Bergi But I mean syntax-wise, how can I do something like files.length? Would I need to first fetch everything and then create an array so I know how many files there are? Then, how would I know what argument to pass it for its name?

Comment: Start with `const fileNames = ['coffee.jpg', 'tea.jpg', 'description.txt']`.

Comment: `values` is already an array, so think about looping through that using `foreach`. but you also need to think about file types. that is, you need to find a way to pass in the type of the file along with the file content, since you need to create the appropriate html element based on the type. right now it knows the type for each because it's hard coded.

Comment: @muratgu You can already distinguish the `values`, images become `Blob` instances while text files become strings.

Answer (score 2):

The second part of the code could be generalised as follows:

```
let urls = ['coffee.jpg', 'tea.jpg', 'description.txt'];

Promise.all(urls.map(fetchAndDecode)).then(values => {
    let elem;
    for (let value of values) {
        if (value instanceof Blob) {
            elem = document.createElement('img');
            elem.src = URL.createObjectURL(value);
        } else if (typeof value === "string") {
            elem = document.createElement('p');
            elem.textContent = value;
        } else {
            console.log("unexpected value type");
            continue;
        }
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const resources = ['coffee.jpg', 'tea.jpg', 'description'];

const resourceRequests = resources.map(fetchAndDecode);

Promise.all(resourceRequests.then(values => {

...
```

Is one way to implement the suggestion. This approach allows for easier modification of the list of resources, but doesn't really change any of the Promise code.

The `.map` code above is equivalent to (resource => fetchAndDecode(resource)) since `fetchAndDecode` takes only the first argument that `.map` would pass to it.